# Cucumber + Webrat doesn't submit forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, cucumber, webrat

I'm new to Cucumber and totally lost as to why this integration test is failing. I have the following scenarios:

```
Scenario: User changes profile

    Given I have an account
    When I change my profile
    Then my profile should be saved

Scenario: User changes login

    Given I have an account
    When I change my login information
    Then my account should be changed
```

And these step definitions:

```
Given /^I have an account$/ do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => 'secret'
    click_button "Sign in"
end

When /^I change my profile$/ do
    visit edit_user_profile_path(@user)
    fill_in "First name", :with => "John"
    fill_in "Last name", :with => "Doe"
    click_button "Update Profile"
end

Then /^my profile should be saved$/ do
    @user.profile.first_name.should == "John"
    @user.profile.last_name.should == "Doe"
end

When /^I change my login information$/ do
    visit edit_user_path(@user)
    fill_in "Email", :with => "foo@example.com"
    click_button "Update Login Information"
end

Then /^my account should be changed$/ do
    @user.email.should == "foo@example.com"
end
```

And I fail the "Then" condition on both scenarios with this message:

```
# Scenario 1
expected: "John"
got: "Test1" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

# Scenario 1
expected: "foo@example.com"
got: "test2@example.com" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

So, in both cases the factory information is still present after submitting the form to update the user login or profile. However, if I test this in a real browser it works perfectly. So, why is this test failing???

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a function to get the current user that is logged in, instead of using @user?

Comment: I have a current_user method, but is that accessible from the test? Do you mean to use instead of @user for updating the forms or for checking the results? In any case I don't see how it would matter, the forms are clearly grabbing the correct user, and the page is loading in webrat correctly (I know because it doesn't raise any errors about what to fill in or click on), which the controller doesn't allow unless the current user is the one editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user is just a variable which lives inside your cucumber code block. It will not be changed. What will be changed in the test is the database record. To check that it was changed indeed you have to visit some page where user name is displayed.
(Just as you do in your real life test)

Comment: Ok, it doesn't make sense to me why it works this way, but I can verify that you are correct. To add a comment for the benefit of future readers: the issue is you need to look up the record again in each step of the scenario. While the `@user` instance variable does pass from step to step, it doesn't stay up-to-date with the data in the database. Replacing all the `@user` references with `User.last` causes the test to perform as expected.

Comment: @Andrew Checking the database works, but it isn't integration test then. Better approach would be, e.g. to refrersh user profile page like 'When I change my profile' - 'And visit profile page' - 'Then I should see "John" within "First Name"'. In fact there are a whole bunch of predefined Web Steps with such assertions so this may work out of the box. Disclaimer: of course everything depends on what exactly do you want to test.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Art. I get that, but as part of my integration tests I'm trying to test things that are displayed to the user as well as several things that aren't. The goal of THIS test is to make sure that submitting the form did in fact change the database and make certain api calls etc (I have some AND clauses I left off because they weren't relevant to why the test wasn't working) Testing what's displayed on the person's profile page is a spec, at least as I have it set up.